# Flip the object without setting a negative scale

Tags: mirror

(Blender 3.2.2, Unity 2021.3.7f1)
How to make a copy of an object only flipped without setting the negative size. Everything would be fine, but as soon as I apply bones to an object, the Unity game engine immediately makes objects with a negative size transparent on the outside. I searched for a solution on the Internet, found an answer like Ctrl + A, but this did not help either. [image: ы][image: а]

Comment: So you mean you tried _Ctrl+A > Scale_ and it didn't work? Doing that _should_ reset the scale back to 1,1,1.

Comment: Maybe the normals of the flipped object itself are flipped if the objects look transparent? Try selecting the flipped object in Edit mode in Blender and Alt - N > Recalculate Outside to flip the normals.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett The fact is that nothing changes at all if I use Ctrl + A

Comment: @JohnEason Recalculate Outside - didn't help at all
Recalculate Inside - almost helped, it's kind of not transparent, but the textures seem to be inside the object: https://imgur.com/a/jveXDbM

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I'm sorry, Ctrl + A definitely changes something but does not help with the solution, when reloading the model, it seems like it is less transparent inside or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I combined 2 answers to the question in the comments. I selected my object in *Object Mode* and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then went into *Edit Mode*, selected all edges and used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> *> Flip*. Although the comments recommended using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Outside*, I used *Flip* and it worked.

Comment: maybe your object already had inverted normals thats why `Ctrl+A` > Scale did not work. because flipping with negative scale and applying it will 100% work. sorry but that's fact.